# how to obsolete controller name from Html.ActionLink in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html.actionlink

I want to obsolete controller name from **Html.ActionLink**
because I defined my controller in route how to do this,
 because if I leave controller name blank in **Html.ActionLink**
 mvc3 automatically put current controller name in Action Link.

Comment: What do you mean by "i want to obsolete controller name from Html.ActionLink"

Comment: I think OP doesn't want to specify the controller twice, both on the route and the action link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you named your route, you can use `RouteLink` instead of `ActionLink`.
You'll only have to specify the name of the route, not the controller.
Here's an example of a named route:

```
routes.MapRoute( "myRoute", 
                 "doStuff/Now", 
                 new {controller = "MyController", action = "DoIt"} );
```

And here's how to use it in your view

```
Html.RouteLink( "Do it!", "myRoute" );
```

Please [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703603) for full details on RouteLink.